# argument can not pass in to factorygirl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, cucumber, capybara, factory-bot

I like to pass argument in the factorygirl, But its shows an error. My code is

```
When /^I create (\d+) companies and a company "([^"]*)" with "([^"]*)"$/ do |n,arg1,arg2|
  create_companies n.to_i
  click_on("Companies")
  companies = FactoryGirl.create(:company, arg1: "#{arg2}", sub: 123)  
  companies.save_profile
end
```

I am passing `arg1` in to the `Facorygirl`. But Its show error as

```
undefined method `arg1=' for #<Company:0x0000000c150ed0> (NoMethodError)
```

How may pass arg1 to factorygirl.

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: You're passing `arg2`, not `arg1`.

Comment: Ho sorry. I update the code.

Comment: If I catch your drift. Arguments in FC are attribute assignments. If you need to set arg1, you'll need to create an attr_accessor :arg1.

Comment: You need to look at [transient attributes](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#transient-attributes)

Comment: Or perhaps your database isn't set up, which I think would give similar results. If you publish your `Company` model and show us the definition of `companies` from your database, we can provide more help.